# Slide-out tray fence with only a drill

Tags: plywood, drawers, joinery

Building some slide out panels inside kitchen cabinets, with only a drill at my disposal.

**Bottom:** I've selected drawer runners that mount to the bottom of the drawer, I'm thinking I use a slab of 15mm (19/32") plywood as the bottom.

**Fence:** Probably also use 15mm to build a 75mm (3") high fence around the perimeter to prevent stuff from sliding off.

**Handle:** Undecided on putting on a simple handle, but if I did I'd probably attach it to the bottom slab rather than the fence. Probably won't though.

So here is my question: 
What options do I have in terms of joinery, given I have only a drill at my disposal. I don't have a pocket hole jig, I can't make dados easily, or create dovetails etc. I am thinking using a doweled butt joint is the only real option I have ... combined with glue throughout. This both to connect the fence pieces to one another, as well as to the base plate.

Would welcome any comments.

---

Adding information re. norcal johnny's comment

[image]

Trying to achieve something like this. This is most certainly a functional design, not so much a need to make it look pretty.

[image]

These are not the exact drawer runners I'm using, but indicate how the bottom slab would be mounted.

I can't show a photo of the current situation, as I'm not at the location where I'll be building this. Just preparing myself prior to the journey there. But, it's a situation very typical to the below. Drawer runners will already purchased.

Comment: Can you post a pic of the area, and maybe of something similar you are trying to achieve? Also how important is final look..is this more for use or cosmetics? Thats great you are trying to take this on with only a drill but it will limit design as you obviously realize. :)

Comment: Added some more information. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: You're joking right?  :-) .  Every man knows that a home job is nothing but an excuse to buy more tools.

Answer (score 4):

Some table leg brackets and screws should be all you need, besides the rails which makes no difference in this concept.

Using table leg brackets will allow you to fasten and sandwich the pieces of wood material nicely with minimal unintentional industrial look. :P

**4 Table leg brackets per drawer**

[image]

**Place one bracket on top of each corner of the plywood and screw to the plywood.**

[image]

**Next add the fencing around the sides and fasten with screws.**
[image]

I was going to suggest other methods, like creating a table temp drill press in a table saw style and also using L-brackets but the more I thought of it, the more I realized this may simply be the easiest and best looking results. If you have any other concrens please feel free to ask. Cheers.

Comment: That's a great idea and probably stronger than using dowels. I hope I can find these things in a hardware store near the place I'll be doing this job. Selection of hardware is usually quite limited. Thanks very much for the suggestion!

Comment: As a backup: any thoughts on using dowels for this job?

Comment: If you did dowels, you would need to have a steady hand or set up a jig of some sort that allows your drill to lay sideways and push the fencing towards it like a table saw is used. Make sense? If you take that route, just add 2 dowels, one at top and bottom for each side and at least one every 6 inches where the ply meets the sides. That is usually delicate/finish work and with only a drill it can be done but will require with a lot of patience and care. :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much for the comments! Will look for the braces as a first choice, dowels second.

Comment: My pleasure. If you have any other concerns please feel free to ask.

Comment: @Rob: If using dowels, I would also use glue along the whole length of the wooden surfaces that are being joined. The glue provides most of the strength of the joint.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick good point, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than table-leg brackets, I'd use furniture blocks.

[image]

Advantages

- made for this sort of job
- cheap
- small
- available in several colours

Disadvantages

- ugly
- need a reasonable thickness of wood to hold screws
- not as strong as glued joinery (but you could use these to hold glued butt-joints in place)